# Aggregating trips into a flow network dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I'm just learning Python and I've run into a little snag,
I'm working on a dataset containing 447 regions within Europe and (after cleaning data) around 200,000 freight trips between these regions with differing amounts of freight.

I need to construct two matrices from this data;

1) Aggregated trips between regions (possibly per mode)

2) Aggregated trips between countries (thus without transport within the country)

example of trip data:

```
 From   To  Mode    Volume_ton
     1      2     1      371246
     7      423   2      10587
     245   123    1      6841
```

(so to and from: 447 regions, mode: road=1 rail=2,

How do I use the From and To "coordinates" to construct a new dataframe that adds up all trips over the same combination in the following form:

```
#   0   1    2    3    4    5    6    ...
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

Where the rows are Origin and columns are the destinations

The next question would be how to then aggregate this into a country to country matrix.
The numbers do have codes attached to them and i have constructed a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say for sure without a more reproducible example dataframe. But I would do this:

```
totals = (
    pandas.groupby(by=['To', 'From'])['Volume_ton']
        .sum()
        .unstack(level='From')
)
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your anwser.


I tried putting this code in: 

df_freg_road  = df_flow_road.groupby(['To','From']['Volume_ton']
      .sum()
      .unstack(level='From')
      )

But it gave me the following error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: @Aguywhostudieslogistics "Hard to say for sure without a more reproducible example dataframe"

Comment: @Aguywhostudieslogistics see the "Asking Questions" section in the pandas wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info